# Mock service used in Camel route using Mockito

Tags: spring, apache-camel, mockito, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to mock a service so that mocked service can be used in camel route. But when i try to use method `findByStatus` it gives this exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route jobRoute at: >>> Transform[bean{camelJobService, method=findByStatus}] <<< in route: Route(jobRoute)[[From[direct:start]] -> [Transform[bean{came... because of org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: findByStatus not found on bean: Mock for CamelJobService, hashCode: 1172605816 of type: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1072)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:944)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3245)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2968)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2799)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2795)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2818)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2795)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2764)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader$7.execute(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:515)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestHelper.doToSpringCamelContexts(CamelSpringTestHelper.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.handleCamelContextStartup(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:509)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.loadContext(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringTestContextLoader.loadContext(CamelSpringTestContextLoader.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: findByStatus not found on bean: Mock for CamelJobService, hashCode: 1172605816 of type: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1642)
    at org.apache.camel.model.language.MethodCallExpression.validateHasMethod(MethodCallExpression.java:247)
    at org.apache.camel.model.language.MethodCallExpression.createExpression(MethodCallExpression.java:204)
    at org.apache.camel.model.language.ExpressionDefinition.createExpression(ExpressionDefinition.java:177)
    at org.apache.camel.model.TransformDefinition.createProcessor(TransformDefinition.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
```

My `camel-context.xml:`

```
<bean id="camelJobService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target"> <bean class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"> <constructor-arg value="com.asklytics.camel.db.service.CamelJobService" /> </bean> </property>
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <spring:route id="jobRoute" startupOrder="2">
        <spring:from uri="direct:start"/>
        <spring:transform>
            <spring:method ref="camelJobService" method="findByStatus"></spring:method>
        </spring:transform>

        <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </spring:route>
</camelContext>
```

I know method `findByStatus` is not found on mock bean service. But How can I mock the service so that it is able to find it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can mock beans like that. You can only mock endpoints which makes sense since endpoints may not be available. Why would you want to mock the bean?
See the documentation.
http://camel.apache.org/mock.html

Comment: `findByStatus` hits database which I do not want to that is why I need to mock service. I want it to return the object which I created in test not from database.

Comment: Well why don't you write a processor with a simple java class to mimic that response and use that as bean?